# get access to id in loop using react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm looping through an array using map and I can get access to user inputs using onChange and useState however how do I store the specific id for the  thats being edited so I can use that id in a PUT request?

```
const [departments, setDepartments] = useState([])
const [newName, setNewName] = useState('')
const [id, setId] = useState(0)

{
  departments.map((department) => {

    return (
      <tr id={department.departmentId}>
        <td>{department.name}</td>
        <td>{department.departmentId}</td>
        <td><input type="department" onChange={e => setNewName(e.target.value)} /> <button className="table-btn btn" onClick={handleChange}>Save</button></td>
      </tr>
    )
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed variable `newName` to object, then write two properties `name` and `id`

```js
    const [departments, setDepartments] = useState([])
    const [newName, setNewName] = useState({})
    
    const handleChange = () => {
      //your api call
      console.log(newName)
    }

    {departments.map((department) => {

                const {departmentId, name} = department;

                return (
                  <tr id={departmentId}>
                    <td>{name}</td>
                    <td>{departmentId}</td>
                    <td>
                      <input type="department" onChange={e => setNewName({name:e.target.value, id:departmentId)}/>
                      <button  className="table-btn btn" onClick={handleChange}>Save</button>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                )
    })}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! feel very silly seeing the solution should of thought of that

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you need to update the name of the department when you change the input, so here's a way you could do that:

```js
const { useState } = React;
const App = () => {
  const [departments, setDepartments] = useState([
    {
      departmentId: "abc",
      name: "ABC",
    },
    {
      departmentId: "efg",
      name: "EFG",
    },
  ]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log("PUT request goes here");
  };

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {departments.map(({ name, departmentId }, index) => (
          <tr key={departmentId} id={departmentId}>
            <td>{name}</td>
            <td>{departmentId}</td>
            <td>
              <input
                type="department"
                onChange={({ target: { value } }) => {
                  const newArr = [...departments];
                  newArr[index].name = value;
                  setDepartments(newArr);
                }}
              />{" "}
              <button className="table-btn btn" onClick={handleClick}>
                Save
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Very cool! thank you.